# Mesosphere: Webserver on port 5050 not responding / Failed to create Zookeeper, zookeeper_init: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apache-zookeeper, mesos, mesosphere

I have followed the instructions over at [digital oceans](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-production-ready-mesosphere-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04) on how to setup mesosphere on Ubuntu 14.04. Everything went fine up to the chapter **"Configure Service Init Rules and Restart Services"**.

The issue is that on port 5050 no website is displayed (connection refused) when accessed via the public IP as well as from localhost, iptables is empty.

My setup running on VMware Workstation are 3 mesos-masters and 7 mesos-slaves, each of them running **Ubuntu 14.04 server**. Installation and configuration was done with clusterssh to ensure all VMs are set-up equally.

```
root@host01:~# uname -a
Linux host01 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Mesos-Master is running**

```
root@host01:~# service mesos-master status
mesos-master start/running, process 15445
```

**Mesos-Master is listening on port 5050**

```
root@host01:~# netstat -tulpen
Aktive Internetverbindungen (Nur Server)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          10623       884/sshd        
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.9:5050        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          97294       21023/mesos-master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          10625       884/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN      105        10824       882/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::2888                 :::*                    LISTEN      105        97052       882/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::36584                :::*                    LISTEN      105        10761       882/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::3888                 :::*                    LISTEN      105        10825       882/java        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2276            0.0.0.0:*                           0          9175        638/dhclient    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          9254        638/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 :::60505                :::*                                0          9176        638/dhclient
```

In **/var/log/mesos/mesos-master.ERROR** it says:

```
F0514 10:35:04.625597 10451 zookeeper.cpp:132] Failed to create Zookeeper, zookeeper_init: No such file or directory
```

Being new to mesos and zookeeper I don't know how to resolve this issue and would kindly ask for your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the below path:
- /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
- /etc/zookeeper/conf/myid
- /etc/mesos-master/quorum
- /var/lib/zookeeper/myid

Make sure zoo.cfg contains all the server list with same value as in myid file for each node. One more thing, delete all the backup file if exist at that location and disable the firewall.